# Check for win in four in a row

Tags: java

I coded this to check if someone won, but it looks like it will only check for if someone won by horizontal, any ideas to check if someone won by vertical and diagonal?

```
 public boolean checkForVictory() {
        int xInRow = 0;
        int oInRow = 0;
        boolean playerOneWins = false;
        boolean playerTwoWins = false;
        //loop through the map and check if every cell contains x or o and then add the number. If in the next cell is another character, then put it back to 0
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<6; j++){
                if(j == 0){
                    xInRow = 0;
                    oInRow = 0;
                }
                if(Map.getInstance().map[i][j].contains("x")){
                    xInRow++;
                    oInRow = 0;
                }
                if(Map.getInstance().map[i][j].contains("o")){
                    oInRow++;
                    xInRow = 0;
                }
                if(xInRow == 4)
                    playerOneWins = true;
                if(oInRow == 4)
                    playerTwoWins = true;
            }
        }
        if(playerOneWins){
            GameModel.getInstance().player1.playerVictory = true;
            return true;
        }
        if(playerTwoWins){
            GameModel.getInstance().player2.playerVictory = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you can use a customized version of DFS/BFS. have you tried that?

Comment: New to java, not sure what you mean?

Comment: Depth first search / Breadth first search is nothing specific to Java. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Game%20Trees/pix/8-puzzle.bmp
Check this image to get an intuition and try implementing it.